# What happened to the Espheni ships and the technology they brought with them?

Tags: falling-skies

In the TV show *Falling Skies*, the alien invaders called the Eshpeni appear to have only limited technology for a space faring species. Their ships are nowhere to be seen, their mechs seem to use projectile weapons and they rely on scavenged local materials and power (like nuclear plants) for many of their needs.

On the other hand, (season 3 spoiler ahead)

> the Volm have powerful energy weapons and at least one large interstellar vessel that landed on Earth.

Was there any indication in early seasons as to why this is? Did they crash here? Or are they from a 'third world' planet or something?

Comment: You say they "rely on scavenged local materials and power (like nuclear plants) for many of their needs" as though that's a *bad* thing. One of their strengths really seems to be their ability to make a single, devastating assault on a planet to cripple most of the military resistance, and then leave an invading force that has the capability to survive, fight and grow their army using primarily what's available on the planet itself.

Comment: It may be a good thing, but in the case of Earth, it gave their victims an opening to fight back -- time to organize, sabotage things (like the nuclear plant).

Answer (score 5):

I believe that thir main forces might just left the planet after initial conquest, somewhere during show there was quote - about initial invasion - that their ships were powerful enough to 'pick off' human ships ( that avoided initial EMP and destruction) straight from the water when they were combating them.

Also their method of conquest, as far as I remember, was EMP + bombing of major military installations + swarms of Mechs and skitters on whatever still stands.. that's hardly a 'laser, phaser & hi-teach' means that Volmes seems to prefer.

Also they seems to focus more on bio-technology ( harness, 'slavery' etc ) than 'hi-tech'.. or at least they do not deploy / rely on  it on "common" scale, what is quite reasonable considering fe. elements such as 'rebel skitters' that could capture and use that advanced weaponry against them and that "not so much advanced" projectile weapons they employ with mechs and super-mechs are vastly superior to whatever humans / rebels may gather anyway

Comment: That sounds quite reasonable, especially if their strategy is to net as many planets as possible, rather than nail down absolute control on the ones they already have.